# Questions about solutions of $x'=f(x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, class $C^1$ and consider $x'=f(x^2)$

Can all solutions be strictly decreasing?

Is every solution either constant or strictly monotonic?

I don't know how to answer those questions. How to use the fact that $f$ is $C^1$?

Could you help?

Comment: Try to find examples of $f$ where these behaviors happen. for example $f=-x$, $f=x$, etc...

Comment: For $x'=- x^2$, $x'= -3x^2 - x^4$, etc all solutions are strictly decresing. But for $x'=-x, \ x'=x, \ x'= x^3$ solutions cannot be monotonic. So the answers seem to be yes and no. Is it correct?

Comment: No, because $f(x)=\sqrt x$ isn't $C^{1}$.

Comment: You're right. But either way, $x'=x^3$ or $x'=8x^5 + x^9$ are counterexamples to the second statement, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider $f(t)=t$ then you have the ODE $x'=x^2.$ Solving it  we get $x(t)=\frac{-1}{t+c}$ which is strictly increasing.

If you consider $f(t)=-t$ then you have the ODE $x'=-x^2.$ Solving it  we get $x(t)=\frac{1}{t+c}$ which is strictly decreasing.

So we have that there are non-constant solutions and solutions that are not strictly decreasing.

Now, since $f\in C^1$ we have uniqueness of solutions. Thus if $x(t)$ is a non monotonic solution and satisfies $x'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ (denote $x(t_0)=x_0)$ then $f(x(t_0))=0.$ But $x_1(t)\equiv x_0$ would be a different solution of the Cauchy problem $x'=f(x^2),x(t_0)=x_0,$ in contradiction with uniqueness of solutions. Thus the only solutions satisfying $x'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ are the constant solutions. This shows that any non-constant solution satisfies $x'>0$ or $x'<0$ and, in consequence, is monotonic.

Comment: Thank you. It is all very clear now. The solution can't start decreasing or increasing because then at some point $x'=0$ and that would mean that the solution is constant as you proved above. Thanks again!